# How can Linux/Ubuntu be installed safely on ChromeBook?

Tags: chromebook, chromeos

Is installing Ubuntu on my Chromebook potentially dangerous to anything on my Chromebook? I got it as a gift, so I don't want to destroy anything that is important on the laptop.
Also, which is better for being able to safely install Ubuntu: ChrUbuntu
or Crouton?
I'm using the Samsung Chromebook 3 (as described by the quick-start manual).
Does that make any other differences as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Also off-topic according to the accepted answer at Meta: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14079/crouton-install-vs-crouton-based-ubuntu-problem

Comment: I don't agree, 1.) It's about installing Ubuntu on a device, preferably a setup where other users around here can help out with further questions. 2.) It's a legitimate concern of a user to ask what could possibly go wrong (we do indeed have answers from some users around here that leave you with an unsupported terrible setup of Ubuntu Touch on a Meizu for example), certain things to avoid, how to recover from possible mistakes and what is recommended for the default setup.

Comment: karel gave the right direction, you should install Ubuntu similar to a dual boot experience which is the typical setup we support here on AskUbuntu for asking questions. if you follow the instructions on chrx.org there is not much that can go wrong but you may encounter similar show stoppers to the ones I faced installing Ubuntu on a model with similar hardware (Lenovo N22). A good idea would be to migrate your question where non-Ubuntu flavors are [on-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) too or ask a new question there if you have any issues. (I recently adjusted my filters for this topic.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrubuntu is a true dual boot and loads that way. Chrubuntu no longer works and will not be updated. It's potentially dangerous to install Chrubuntu on Chromebooks with newer models of Intel processors.

Crouton runs side by side with Chrome OS. Crouton is the better choice if you're not familiar with Ubuntu and just need a separate OS to launch some apps you need. You can run a music player app like Rhythmbox in Crouton and then switch back to ChromeOS in a matter of seconds for quick seamless browsing while it plays. Crouton also has less potential problems with glitchy device drivers for Chromebook hardware than Chrubuntu.

[chrx](https://chrx.org/) is a currently maintained project for dual booting various Linux distributions alongside ChromeOS. The default distribution is GalliumOS. GalliumOS is derived from Xubuntu and developed specifically for compatibility and optimized performance on Chromebook hardware. The downside of chrx is that it doesn't support ARM processors and firmware updates are required or recommended for newer models of Intel processors, so it's also more dangerous than Crouton.

Comment: ChrUbuntu hasn't been updated I for a long time as far as I know and doesn't work well with newer releases of Ubuntu, a good answer should recommend a solution that is more up to date, which I think would be https://chrx.org/.