# Chromebook to Ubuntu without crouton

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

I only see tutorials for installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook with crouton, but I want fully working Ubuntu!
Is it possible to Install Ubuntu on a Chromebook without crouton?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Installing-Linux-Dead-Badger-Snyder/dp/1894953479

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Linux/Ubuntu be installed safely on ChromeBook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865206/how-can-linux-ubuntu-be-installed-safely-on-chromebook) and [Is it possible to dual-boot chrome OS and Ubuntu 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866590/is-it-possible-to-dual-boot-chrome-os-and-ubuntu-16-10)

Answer (score 1):

To install a full Linux distribution on your chromebook you have multiple choices.
You can use chrx to make a dual boot.
Or you can install directly a full version of Ubuntu (best to go for LUbuntu or Xubuntu).

I would recommend to install [GalliumOS](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Welcome_to_the_GalliumOS_Wiki) as it is derived from XUbuntu and it's optimized for chromebooks.

To do this, you should follow GalliumOS installation steps:

- First, you have to enable developer mode on your chromebook (and remove all data on your disk).
- Second, you have to update your firmware to be able to boot on a USB key.
- Third, install your Ubuntu/Gallium, or a dual boot using chrx.

Step one and two are really well documented on GalliumOS's wiki, you will find all your answers here.

Comment: It's not possible to install "plain" Ubuntu (or any of its official flavours) on a Chromebook because of the different boot process. -1