# Why doesn't Ubuntu receive keyboard or mouse input on Chromebook?

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, mouse, chromebook

I have a chromebook, which I set up to boot from a usb. It boots into desktop, no problem, but then doesn't respond to keyboard presses or mouse input. Of course, it does before I boot from usb, I can type "help" and move the mouse. I confirm that it the same problem occurs with Zorin and elementaryOS. Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: What chromebook do you have? What version of Ubuntu do you have? Is there any more information you can include about *exactly* what happens?

Comment: There is a lot of information outhtere about Ubuntu on Chromebooks: some work perfectly, others will never work, depending the chips used.
Please post exactly what hardware you have and what you think the chip may be.

Comment: @NonnyMoose I have a HP Chromebook 11 with an Intel Celeron N3xxx

Comment: @Piloti https://www.amazon.com/HP-Chromebook-Celeron-Chrome-11-v020nr/dp/B01LCT3XX8/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

Comment: OK, from a quick scoot around I have not found anything that describes installing Ubuntu successfully. However there are a number of alternatives, like running Cruton, see here https://liliputing.com/2013/10/running-ubuntu-apps-hp-chromebook-11-video.html .

Also, there is a link to `Ask` here, https://askubuntu.com/a/914593/683272
 which discusses GalliumOS which seems to have some traction.

Happy reading.