# How do I remove ChromeOS from my HP chromebook?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook, crouton, chromeos

ChromeOS keeps taking up CPU usage to 100%, and messes with me running Linux apps, so I would like to remove ChromeOS and go Ubuntu-only. Linux was installed on this [14-ca052wm Chromebook](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06085999) using [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/README.md) ([more](https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/)) and here's a screen shot from gparted [image: screenshot from gparted] of my 12 drive partitions.

Comment: Very complex process with a lot of steps: See https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-chromebook/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm and https://askubuntu.com/questions/865206/how-can-linux-ubuntu-be-installed-safely-on-chromebook  Maybe a lighter flavor of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu, may be helpful: https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: I checked for one of the steps and flashrom --wp-disable doesn't work I've checked if theres is write protect screw and I don't see one.

Comment: Not required by https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-chromebook/